# Wait a Promise to finish in an express function

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, promise, axios

I have a post call in Express which needs to be validated, so I created a javascript file called "validator.js" to check the passed values before proceeding. One of the methods in "validator.js" needs to do an axios call, but it obviously needs time before fullfill data. So I solved with async/await like this

```
router.post("/add_to_favorites", passport.authenticate("local"), async(req, res) => 
    { let validation = await validateMedia(req.body);

if (validation.error) {
    return res.status(400).json(validation.message);
   }
```

"validateMedia" is the function which calls validator.js.

---

**What is the best way to handle this axios async call considering the following code?**

**Express**

```
router.post("/add_to_favorites", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => 
    { let validation = validateMedia(req.body);
if (validation.error) {
    return res.status(400).json(validation.message);
  }
}
```

**validator.js**

```
const validateMedia = data => {
  if (data.mediaType !== "movie" && data.mediaType !== "serie") {
    return {
      error: true,
      message: "Media type is not valid"
    };
  }

  if (data.mediaType === "movie") {
    axios.get(`/${data.mediaType}/${data.mediaId}`).then(response => {
      if (data.mediaTitle === response.data.title) {
        return { error: false, message: "Success" };
      }
      return { error: true, message: "Failed" };
    });
  }
return { error: false, message: "Checked values" };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have shared limited info. Need to how you defined `validateMedia` does it return a Promise using `new Promise` or is it a `async` function? In `async-await` `await` waits for promise to get resolved.

Read more about [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promise here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Depending upon the info you have provided this should work if `validateMedia` function is like:

With Promise:

```
function validateMedia(data) {
  // Using promise here
  return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
    if (data.mediaType !== "movie" && data.mediaType !== "serie") {
      return resolve({    // Call resolve function to return success
        error: true,
        message: "Media type is not valid"
      });
    }

    if (data.mediaType === "movie") {
      // This is the function needs to wait for.
      axios.get(`/${data.mediaType}/${data.mediaId}`).then(response => {
        if (data.mediaTitle === response.data.title) {
          // Call resolve function to return success
          return resolve({ error: false, message: "Success" });
        }
        // Call reject function to return error
        return reject({ error: true, message: "Failed" });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

With async-await:

```
async function validateMedia(data) {

  if (data.mediaType !== "movie" && data.mediaType !== "serie") {
      return {
        error: true,
        message: "Media type is not valid"
      };
  }

  if (data.mediaType === "movie") {
      try {
          // This is the function needs to wait for. if axios.get() returns a promise
          let response = await axios.get(`/${data.mediaType}/${data.mediaId}`);

          if (data.mediaTitle === response.data.title) {
              return { error: false, message: "Success" };
          }
          return { error: true, message: "Failed" };
      }
      // If axios.get() throws error or rejects promise
      catch (err) {
          return { error: true, message: "Failed" };
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this way shouldn't I be constrained to wrap (req, res), in router.post, in an async function? Because I've just tested it and works only with "async (req, res)" and "await validateMedia(req.body)". validateMedia function just returns an object with "error" and "message" (I've edited my question). Sorry for limited info, I was trying to avoid to copy/paste all code, but your requested info was actually useful to know.